# Wordpress child theme activated and broke website, how can this be fixed?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming

I uploaded a child theme to my wordpress site and activated it and it's completely broken my site now. Every time I try to go to the site (on Google Chrome) I get the message that "It's now working and is currently unable to handle this request." and also the error is "http error 500" is there any way to fix this? On Safari it just shows a blank white page, nothing else. I'm really nervous that I won't be able to access my site anymore which would be detrimental. I really really really need to be able to fix this.

Comment: you'll have to change the theme, is the admin area not working.  You may find this helpfull, it says you can just delete the theme, I've never tried that though https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-theme-manually  By the way it took me like 2 seconds to google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming the child themes folder to gain access the /wp-admin. If you are still seeing a message that something is working then make sure the .maintenance file is removed from the root of the website. As another option to access the wp-admin you can login to the database and edit the wp_options table which will have two rows for the theme. These 2 rows will currently have the name of the child theme, switching this back to the parent theme name should revert the change that you made.

Once you have successfully re-enabled the parent theme then you will want to make sure that you created the child theme properly and figure out which core theme files were edited to cause the child theme activation to break the site. You could also enable php error reporting from within a php.ini and/or the wp-config.php file currently so you can get a more detailed error to troubleshoot the cause of the issue.